# How to get table legend with SEQ field in MS-Word when copying from HTML?

Tags: microsoft-word, html

I have a set of generated HTML containing some tables that I want to insert in a MS-Word document:

```
<table width="600" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="1" align="center"><tbody>
  <tr>
    <th scope="col">Case</th>
    <th scope="col">Manoeuvre Duration (s)</th>
    <th scope="col">Thruster 1A</th>
    <th scope="col">Thruster 2A</th>
  </tr>
</tbody></table>
<div align="center"><h5>
  Table 1: Pulses Number for X Manoeuver for A
</h5></div>
<table width="600" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="1" align="center"><tbody>
  <tr>
    <th scope="col">Case</th>
    <th scope="col">Manoeuvre Duration (s)</th>
    <th scope="col">Thruster 1A</th>
    <th scope="col">Thruster 2A</th>
  </tr>
</tbody></table>
<div align="center"><h5>
  Table 2: Pulses Number for X Manoeuver for B
</h5></div>
<table width="600" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="1" align="center"><tbody>
  <tr>
    <th scope="col">Case</th>
    <th scope="col">Manoeuvre Duration (s)</th>
    <th scope="col">Thruster 1A</th>
    <th scope="col">Thruster 2A</th>
  </tr>
</tbody></table>
<div align="center"><h5>
  Table 3: Pulses Number for X Manoeuver for C
</h5></div><h4></h4>
```

I generate Table legend number correctly, however, this doesn't allow to update the table of tables because the numbers 1, 2, 3 are not interpreted as {SEQ Table} field by MS-Word.

Does any-one know if I can use a special tag, and which, to inform MS-Word about the table legend field in the HTML ?

BR,
Alexis

Comment: I don't know of an HTML tag that would get Word to do what you want, but you could use a macro to convert them after they're added.

Comment: I thought about it but I'm not skilled in writing macros, and it would be an other question.

Answer (score 0):

After saving modified HTML with MS-Word, I found the tricky tag:

```
<p class=MsoCaption>Table <!--[if supportFields]>
<span style='mso-element:field-begin'></span>
<span style='mso-spacerun:yes'> </span>SEQ Table \* ARABIC <span style='mso-element:field-separator'></span>
<![endif]-->
<span style='mso-no-proof:yes'>1</span>
<!--[if supportFields]>
  <span style='mso-element:field-end'></span>
<![endif]-->Pulses Number for X Manoeuver for A</p>
```

I'll try it out.